# Add class 'active' to menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a sidebar, and i am trying to use Javascript to change the appearance as well as destination page on click. However I have tried many suggestions with no luck and I don't understand why.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enfwuf51/2/)

I've tried using this JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     var url = window.location;
     $('.navigation ul li a[href="'+url+'"]').parent().addClass('active');
});
```

However, once I've added a `href="~/~"` attribute, I get an `"Unknown Command: [Link in href]"` - and the `"active"` class isn't added to the  element.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use `window.location` to get the current page's URL. However, `window.location` is actually an object, that contains multiple properties, and is not a string with the current page's URL. You'll want to use one of the `window.location` properties, most likely `window.location.pathname`. But, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location for your complete list of options.

Comment: Window.location.pathname; solved the issue, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

For your code you need to set the url to `var url = window.location.host+window.location.path';`

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var url = window.location;
// Will only work if string in href matches with location
$('.navigation ul li a[href="'+ url +'"]').parent().addClass('active');

// Will also work for relative and absolute hrefs
$('.navigation ul li a').filter(function() {
    return this.href == url;
}).parent().addClass('active');
```